KQL calculate two sets of average durations with union operator
I need to calculate two sets of average durations i.e. for the last 24 hours and for the last 30 days in the same table as separate columns. Below is my KQL query:
let raw_data = view() {(union isfuzzy=true requests, dependencies)};
let avgDuration30days = toscalar(raw_data | summarize avg(duration) by 
bin(todatetime(now()), 30d));
union isfuzzy=true
    requests,
    dependencies
| project itemType, duration
| summarize avgDuration24hrs = avg(duration) by itemType
| extend avgDuration30days

24 hours time range will be set in the drop down and 30 days time range will be set in the query.
I am seeing the result as below, however the average duration for the last 30 days is not populating as desired:


Where are you running the above query? Monitor or data explorer! @Vinay Nandargi

I am running this in Monitor @Jahnavi

Is your 30 days avg duration logs not accurate? @Vinay Nandargi

Yes, I have pasted the screenshot above. It is a timestamp instead of average duration.

Updated the answer. Please check. @Vinay Nandargi

The issue is with the toscalar() function used in KQL query.
The scalar value always returns a,

A scalar constant value of the evaluated expression. If the result is a tabular, then the first column and first row will be taken for conversion.

There are also few limitations of toscalar() function as detailed here in MS Doc.
I have used a join() operator available in KQL which is used to join the two tables by matching values and forms a new table with the expected results.
Firstly, I retrieved the logs from the raw_data table for a 24-hour duration, and then I obtained the same logs for a 30-day time range. Now, I joined both tables of logs by matching the value of the item type.
let raw_data = view() { union isfuzzy=true requests, dependencies };
let avgDuration30daysinfo = raw_data | where timestamp >= ago(30d) 
| summarize avgDuration30days = avg(duration) by itemType;
raw_data | where timestamp >= ago(24h)
| summarize 24hrsavgDuration = avg(duration) by itemType
| join kind=leftouter avgDuration30daysinfo on itemType
| project-away itemType1



thank you for your valuable inputs. My concern with the join operator is that I need to have 24 hours as configurable time range. It the user wants they should be able to change it to 30 mins, 1 hr, 4 hrs, 12 hrs etc.

The same application can be done with query condition also by changing time generated field. @VinayNandargi
